# SWF loading and flash player upgrade

Tags: javascript, dom, flash, swfobject

I am currently working on a Flash game. In order to ensure the user experience is consistent, I tried to specify the swfVersion and called "swfobject.embedSWF()" using the following code segment.

```
PD.prototype.loadGame=function(){
var flashvars=this.bootData;
var swfVersion = "11.0.1.152";
var xiSwfUrl = "playerProductInstall.swf";
var params = {
    quality: 'high',
    bgcolor: '#ffffff',
    allowscriptaccess: 'always',
    allowfullscreen: 'true',
    wmode:'opaque'
};
var attributes = {
    id:'Main',
    name:'Main',
    align:'middle'
};

var ref=this;
var mainUrl=this.main+this.version+'&t='+(new Date()).getTime();
swfobject.embedSWF(mainUrl, "flashContent", "100%", "590", swfVersion, this.staticPath+xiSwfUrl, flashvars, params, attributes, function(obj){
    if(obj.success){
        ref.swf=obj.ref;
        $(window).resize(function(){
            var width=$('div#flashContentDiv').width();
            ref.swf.setSize(width,590);
        });
    }else{
        $('div#flashContentDiv').css('background','#ffffff');
        $('div#flashContentDiv').html('<div style="padding-top:250px">Please download the latest version of Flash Player from <a target="_blank" href="http://get.adobe.com/flashplayer/">here</a></div>');
    }
});
};
```

However I still get users reporting their cases of failing to load the SWF after upgrading. Should I specify only the major version?

Answer (score 0):

See the [SWFObject docs](http://code.google.com/p/swfobject/wiki/documentation#STEP_3%3a_Embed_your_SWF_with):

> version (String, required) specifies the Flash player version your SWF
>   is published for (format is: "major.minor.release" or "major")

You're specifying more than major.minor.release. Try simplifying to

```
var swfVersion = "11.0.1";
```